# https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ Is this a crawler bot

Tags: bots, googlebot

I see significant traffic coming from this Bot when we send SMS to users. I am trying to get more details about this bot. Any pointers describing what it does, how important it is, and can we block it would be appreciated.
The complete user agent is

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google's SMS app on Android uses this user agent when it crawls the shared URL to generate a preview inside the chat. This is usually a good thing because your customers will see the preview image and page title, rather than just a link. So I would not recommend blocking it.

Comment: When we run an SMS campaign, for a moment this causes a significant increase in traffic to servers. For some reason, this also bypasses the CDN cache, maybe because of user-agent. Any idea, how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but possibly getting lots of traffc from differnt Googel servers. Such that many of the servers are hitting different CDN edge nodes, so the hit rate is bad. As for dealing with it maybe your CDN has a way to share the cache between nodes

Answer (score 3):

You can block google bots on your nginx configuration. Inside of the server{} section, add this:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "developers\.google\.com/\+/web/snippet") {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: Any idea if this bot is of any importance?

Comment: I think they are used to index searches on google, but I'm not sure. I had to block it because it was overloading my server.

Comment: @arariba - did you find a good way to achieve this? I am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This bot is indeed used by some SMS Android applications to fetch a preview of the we page.

Phones using it include (but it has changed over time) Xiaomi, Huawei, Oppo..
For some websites, it is important to block it. For instance, my app is sending a confirmation link, having it clicked by the preview is messing up our stats and follow-up of who wants that.

To block it, you can use the folowwing .htaccess rule (if you use Apache) :

> RewriteEngine on

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*developers.google.com/+/web/snippet.*$ [NC]

> RewriteRule "^.*$" - [F,L]